# How can I send a Whatsapp status (Whatsapp version of stories) using code

Tags: backend, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am creating an app and I need to be able to send Whatsapp statuses using code. I have search online a lot but I could not find a good solution.

My project currently uses typescript, but if there is a way to do so in a different language I would still be very happy with it. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This might help: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises

Comment: @EeEmDee I couldn't find anything there.

Comment: If you look into it, you can see, that you can use the API to send messages programmatically. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/text

Comment: @EeEmDee This is about sending messages. I don't want to send messages I want to send a status (like a story).

Comment: Whatsapp business cloud api does not have any api to send status.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to post a status designed with just text and a colored background. You can also post pictures.
The mandatory parameter should be an array of numbers to which the status will be shown (including your own).

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://gate.whapi.cloud/stories', [
 'body' => '{"background_color":"#00000000","caption_color":"#FFFFFFFF","contacts":["(Numbers to which the status will be shown)","(Numbers to which the status will be shown)"],"font_type":"SANS_SERIF"}',
 'headers' => [
    'accept' => 'application/json',
    'authorization' => 'Bearer Your_Token',
    'content-type' => 'application/json',
 ],
]);
echo $response->getBody();
```

Read more about the method here: https://whapi.readme.io/reference/createstory

You will need a token from [provider](https://whapi.cloud). Attention, this is an unofficial solution, so use at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried this API and it seems to be a bit buggy. Are you aware of any other options? ideally an open source one.

Comment: Nope, haven't met any analogs yet myself who have suggested this. I'm trying to get more access to beta testing WA channel from them now. Apparently others have not implemented all this yet. But statuses works for me, I don't even know about buggy. Maybe it's bad luck.

Comment: this is not official API and I find it risky to use as according to META terms your account get be blocked.